# Accessing JSON data using Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to access a key from the following JSON:

```
{ items = ({a = “string for a”;b = “string for a”;c = “string for a”;},{a = “string for a”;b = “string for a”;c = “string for a”;},{a = “string for a”;b = “string for a”;c = “string for a”;});}
```

For example, I would like to get the value for the first key 'a', but the following returns nil:

```
println(jsonResult["products[product_id]"]
```

Comment: That's not really a valid json string. Could you post the exact string you are trying to parse along with the any parsing code that you have written?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your JSON Example is not valid. Check out with this:

   http://jsoneditoronline.org/
2. I would use a common JSON Plugin for Swift. For Example this:

   https://github.com/owensd/json-swift

And then use:

```
let json : JSON = "your string"
```

And get your objects with:

```
if let myproduct = json["products"]["productid"].array {
    // content of your product (if array)
}
```